# Is using "window.location.pathname" to write route specific logic good practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

I am using main.js file in front-end to write some logic that only executes based on the route it is in.

I am doing this using 'window.location.pathname'.Is this a good practice or is there a better way?

--main.js

```
let url = window.location.pathname;

if(url === '/admin/login'){
    console.log('connected');
    let firstInput = document.querySelector('input');
    firstInput.focus(); 
}

if(url === '/admin/main'){
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
   let navLink = document.querySelector('.navlink a');
   console.log(navLink)
   navLink.style.color = 'black';
}
```

Comment: Opinion question.  My opinion, window.location.hash is cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a good practice or is there a better way?

In my opinion, it's not a great practice and there are better ways.  You would rather the code not be hard-coded to a specific URL path.  It's generally better to have the code operate on the content present rather than the URL.  Then, the content provider can control how the code behaves by just adjusting the content.  Multiple pages can make use of the same feature without having to modify the code.

Since I assume you have somewhat different content in the `/admin/login` and `/admin/main` pages, it seems like you could just use the [`autofocus` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefautofocus) in the content and that would tell the browser where you want the initial focus to be set.

```
<input autofocus type="text" name="id" minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
```

If you were going to do this with code, I'd much rather you use generic code that can apply to any content like this for the focus:

```
 let firstInput = document.querySelector('.firstFocus');
 if (firstInput) {
     firstInput.focus();
 }
```

This will work in any page and it sets first focus to the first object that has a `firstFocus` class attribute.  This lets you use generic code and let the content control what happens.  If your content has a `firstFocus` class on some element in the page, that will become the default focus.  If not, then nothing happens.  The code can work in any page in your site.  The content editor can then determine when to use it without touching code of worrying about paths.

So, any page in your site can take advantage of this by inserting the `firstFocus` class on an element in the page.

```
<input class="firstFocus" type="text" name="id" minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
```

---

For your second `if` statement, you're essentially just applying some custom CSS styling.  That seems like it should again be content based and should use CSS rules to apply the styling.

If you want only the `/admin/main` page to have this particular style, then you can put a class such as `mainAdmin` on the body element in only that page and have a CSS rule that looks for that class:

```
body.mainAdmin { backgroundColor: 'white'}
body.mainAdmin .navlink a {color: 'black'}
```

These CSS rules can then be in your generic CSS styles, but will only be active in pages where the `body` tag has a class of `mainAdmin`.  Again, the creator of the content can control the styling without any custom per-page scripting.